# How to refuse close de Dialog when press Enter Key

Tags: gui-construction

As you can see in the documentation of `CreateDialog`

> In dialogs created with CreateDialog, pressing Return is effectively
>   equivalent to clicking the DefaultButton, and Esc to clicking the
>   CancelButton.
>
> If the dialog contains no DefaultButton or CancelButton, pressing
>   Return or Esc will close the dialog without taking any other action.

I have a input field, for example, and I often press Enter key after I wrote my inputs. 
That what happened is that my window close immediately after that.

How can change this behavior in Dialog?

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the second paragraph you've cited:

> If the dialog contains no `DefaultButton` or `CancelButton`, pressing
>   Enter or Esc will close the dialog without taking any other action.

It turns out the inverse is true as well; you can make the dialog notebook contain an invisible `DefaultButton` that doesn't do anything. Here's an example with `Overlay`:

```
CreateDialog[Overlay[{DefaultButton[], InputField[]}, {2}, 2]]
```

In the arguments to `Overlay`, `{2}` says to only display the second element (the `InputField`), and `2` says to allow selections etc. in the second element (again, the `InputField`).

Note there's no need to specify `DefaultButton` beyond its defaults. Also, I'm a little surprised that `Overlay` can make the `DefaultButton` "present" like this but at the same time "turned off". But there it seems to be. Good for this situation at least `:)`

Comment: thanks, I was stucked and this was a part of the problem.

Comment: @d555, no problem, glad to help. I updated the answer a bit, turns out the second argument of `Overlay` can be used to make the `DefaultButton` "present" yet invisible still. So it's simpler than I'd originally explained.

Answer (score 0):

In a dialog window, use the option `NotebookEventActions -> {"WindowClose" :> {}}` to avoid any default behaviors associated with the ESC or Enter keys.  In the example below, even the DefaultButton won't give DialogReturn[] if you press Enter.

```
CreateDialog[
DefaultButton["close", DialogReturn[]],
NotebookEventActions -> {"WindowClose" :> {}}]
```

However, this dialog can be closed via keyboard shortcuts such as CMD + W on Mac, and Alt + F4 on Windows.  If you want to remove that functionality as well, add `WindowFrameElements -> {}`, which removes the upper close button, which then removes the keyboard shortcuts for those buttons.  In this case, you must use the DialogReturn[] button to close the Dialog.  See below.

```
CreateDialog[
 DefaultButton["close", DialogReturn[]], 
 NotebookEventActions -> {"WindowClose" :> {}},
 WindowFrameElements -> {}]
```